# Backbone JS View Events not Firing?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I'm trying to play around with Backbone JS and so far everything seems to be making sense and working smoothly.

However with the code below, my custom events do not seem to be firing.  Anything in the below code stand out as to why that might be?  Do I need to "initialize" anything in the View?  Any other pointers on the code/structure would be cool as well.  Below is my full JS/HTML.

JS

```
var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var TodoCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: Todo,
    url: '/Home/Todos'

});

var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({

    // where it should listen, required?
    el: $(".content"),

    events: {
        "keypress #new-todo": "enter"
    },

    initialize: function () {
        // _.bindAll(this, "render", "createOnEnter");
        // this.collection.bind("all", this.render);
    },

    hi: function () {
        alert('ohai');
    },

    render: function () {
        var lis = '';
        $.each(this.collection.models, function () {
            lis += '<li>' + this.get('Text') + '</li>';
        });
        $('#todo-list').append(lis);
        return this.el;
    },

    enter: function (e) {
        alert('hi');
    }

});


var TodoController = Backbone.Controller.extend({

    routes: {
        "": "todos"
    },

    initialize: function (options) { },

    todos: function () {
        var todolist = new TodoCollection();
        todolist.fetch({
            success: function (data) {
                var appview = new AppView({ collection: data });
                appview.render();
            }
        });
    }

});

$(function () {
    window.app = new TodoController();
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="todoapp">
    <div class="content">
        <input id="new-todo" placeholder="What needs to be done?" type="text" />
        <div id="todos">
            <ul id="todo-list">
            </ul>
        </div>
        <a href="#">say hey</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
el: $(".content")
```

Try this:

```
var appview = new AppView({ el:$(".content"), collection: data });
```

You cannot call a jQuery there because the DOM is not yet created. You must do it when the view is loaded either as my example or in the initialize.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm still a bit confused why the DOM wouldn't be created at that point.  I kick off the controller at the bottom and wrap it inside a document ready call.  Then my controllers news up the AppView, so at that point wouldn't it be the first time calling 'el' ?

Comment: var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({}) is evaluated as the browser reads it. You instantiate it in the document ready call but since _el_ is not a function, it will be evaluated as part of the extend.

Comment: Can someone explain why the Backbone.js Todo example doesn't need to pass in parameters when they create their AppView? They have this comment at the top of todo.js, "// Load the application once the DOM is ready, using `jQuery.ready`:", but I don't see them doing anything to ensure that the DOM is ready. Thanks.

Comment: Never mind. I think I figured it out. It's because they wrapped everything inside of $(function {});, correct?

Comment: Yes the element is already created when the view is interpreted by the browser

Comment: Also you can set it as function in model definition `el: function(){ return $('.content') },`. In this case it should be executed after DOM creation.

Comment: instead of `el: $('.content')`, you can do `el: '.content'`, without the wrapper, and then you don't need to pass it each time you create the view.  backbone will wrap the string in `$()` when initializing. this is a better solution than passing it every time the view is created.

Comment: *"You cannot call a jQuery there because the DOM is not yet created."* - how can you be so sure..? What if the `<script>` tags are added at the end of `<body>`..?

Answer (score 16):

Additionally, for your events to work, you must bind your content in the render function to this.el. Events are all bound to the element you specify, so it follows that you need to have your event-generating elements bound as children to the element which acts as the delegator.

Comment: i'd like this comment twice, but I can't, it was exactly my problem, 10x!

Comment: this has changed now, too, with the update to the Backbone API. There is now a method available for setting the el dynamically, and if that is used, delegateEvents() is called automagically by that function.

Comment: I don't know backbone very well, but I think this would be solved by not specifying the el attribute and inside the render function doing $('.content').wrap(this.el);

Comment: +1 ! "it follows that you need to have your event-generating elements bound as children to the element which acts as the delegator." improved my understanding of el and events

Answer (score 1):

The approved answer has a drawback. You can not be very dynamic if you set { el: $(".content") }. It is not possible to reuse ".content"-Element inside your DOM. As soon as you call remove() on this view $(".content") will be gone too.

I use another parameter to pass that information:

```
{ renderTarget: $("#content") }.
```

and insert my view into the DOM at start of render:

```
initialize: function (options) { 
    options = options || {}; 
    this.renderTarget = options.renderTarget || this.renderTarget;
},
render: function () {
    if (this.renderTarget) {
       $(this.renderTarget).html(this.el);
    }
    ... render stuff into $(this.el) ...
    return this;
}
```